# How to do a comparison function in C#

Tags: c#, linq, comparison

Say I have elements (X, Y, and Z) in a list, I have a function, that generates a percentage, of how much two objects resemble each other.

What I want to do, is run X against Y and Z using my compareElements, so:

```
compareElements(X,Y); // equals 55
compareElements(X,Z); // equals 60
```

Then Y against X and Z

```
compareElements(Y,X); // equals 55
compareElements(Y,Z); // equals 62
```

Then Z against Y and X

```
compareElements(Z,X); // equals 60
compareElements(Z,Y); // equals 62
```

Then, I return the highest value, which is 62.

Obviously, there's some repetition there, I don't need the repetition, but I'm not sure how to eliminate it.

How do I structure my LINQ query, or a function/algorithm to do this comparison on every element, without the repetition?

I'd prefer to use LINQ if I can, as I'm being passed an enumerable and the function returns before the list is actually enumerated, so we can save the cost of performing the compare, until the list is enumerated.

All I need is that highest value, of the compare functions, 62.

Note: *My actual result set I'm working with averages between 3 and 10 elements in the list, that need to be ran through this compare function.*

Comment: Do you have a  List<Tuple<int, int, int>> or similar? or how do you have the X, Y, Z items organized?

Comment: Do you also need to know which two object resulted in the highest value?

Comment: If you just want the highest element, can't you just use List.Sort().Last()?

Comment: @SebastianPiu X, Y, Z, elements are all in an enumerable. I don't care which object resulted in the highest, as that's stored with my Compare function

Comment: @lthibodeaux biggest reason for wanting linq, is to put it in an enumerable, and  I have it yielded across, the compare operation is very expensive, and I don't want it done until it absolutely has to run.

Comment: Using LINQ, you're going to force `n² - n` comparisons when it should only take `.5(n² - n)` ([see Wolfram for comparison](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=compare+sum+%281+to+n%29+n+-1+to+%28n%5E2+-+n%29)). I'd suggest doing it the right way rather than using LINQ, or hide the implementation away using a compiler extension that allows you to call a custom function on your list like `.CompareGroup()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of readability, I would write an iterator block to generate the comparisons in a non-repetitive manner:

```
IEnumerable<Tuple<T, T>> GetComparisons<T>(IEnumerable<T> elements)
{
    var visited = new List<T>();

    foreach(T current in elements)
    {
        foreach(T previous in visited) 
            yield return new Tuple<T, T>(current, previous);

        visited.Add(current);
    }
}
```

Then you can do the following:

```
var highScore = GetComparisons(listOfElements)
                    .Select(x=>compareElements(x.Item1, x.Item2)
                    .Max();
```

(That said I prefer Smelch's suggestion for situations where there's no practical reason to use LINQ or iterators, such as having a need for composable routines.)

Comment: your solution ended up working out pretty well for me and the client! GetComparisons was a really good idea!

Answer (score 8):

I'd be inclined to do it like this:

```
int count = list.Count;
var query = from index1 in Enumerable.Range(0, count)
            from index2 in Enumerable.Range(index1 + 1, count - (index1 + 1))
            select ComputeSimilarity(list[index1], list[index2]);
var maxSimilarity = query.Max();
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure I'm understanding you correctly, but try something like this:

```
    public int compareElementList(List<Element> elements)
    {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < elements.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int q = i + 1; q < elements.Count; q++)
            {
                result = Math.Max(result, compareElements(elements[i], elements[q]));
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

This will eliminate the duplicate comparisons for you. It doesn't use LINQ, but I think it's still pretty readable.

**UPDATE**: Here is my version modified to handle IEnumerables. It varies from Jon Hanna's in that it doesn't create a new List, it just keeps track of two iterators.

```
    public int compareElementEnumerable(IEnumerable<Element> elements)
    {
        int result = 0, i = 0, q = 1;
        foreach (Element el in elements)
        {
            foreach (Element el2 in elements)
            {
                if (q > i)
                {
                    result = Math.Max(result, compareElements(el, el2));
                }
                q++;
            }
            i++;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Seems pretty spot-on. LINQ's a tool, and if someone with a bunch of hammers asked how to put nails into things, then there's no point showing how to use a screwdriver to do it, even if they said they'd like to use one.

Comment: This may also end up being more performant. I suspect that any method that uses LINQ will either duplicate a lot of comparisons or generate a lot of intermediate objects.

Comment: @SeanU problem is I'm being passed an IEnumerable, I'd have to cast this to a list or array first? Wouldn't that be just as expensive?

Comment: @SeanU The LINQ-based answer here from Eric Lippert is pretty close to this in approach, and only has a couple of light-weight intermediates. I still like the above.
It does occur to me, that since `compareElements` returns a precentage, one could short-circuit it if `result` ever gets set to 100 as nothing can beat that.

Comment: @BrianDeragon Hard to tell without profiling. But my instinct says creating (n(n-1))/2 Tuples (one for each comparison) will hit the heap a lot harder than creating a n-element List or Array.

Comment: I think I would like to note somewhere the assumption that CompareElements returns >=0 number. Otherwise, initialize result to Int32.MinValue.

Comment: @BrianDeragon, if you're getting an IEnumerable, you should use Eric Lippert's answer. Otherwise you would have to use nested foreaches and keep track of your i and q iterators inside them, which would be ugly and probably not perform any better than the LINQ. Very possibly, it would perform worse.

Comment: @BrianDeragon I think we all read "list" in the question as referring to the type of that name. I've added an answer that's close to this, but deals with the case of the source enumeration not being a list.

Comment: @Smelch Eric's assumes a list or array too, he's indexing into it.

Comment: @SolutionYogi, it's in the question that the result is >= 0 as it's a percentage.

Comment: Yes thanks for the additional updates, I actually can't short-circuit out on 100, simply cause I have to have them choose which comparison/match with the percentage given they like best. Going to try and profile a few of the answers here to see what gives the most usability, performance, and readability.

Comment: Brian, you said above that you only need the number, so you'll lose the information on which pair gave you that match without short-cutting. Are you sure you just need the highest number? I ask, because the problem where you need that is quite different with different answers.

Comment: @JonHanna in my match info class it keeps track of this, stores it in an internal dictionary I later reference. For everyone else, SeanU's answer gave the best/fastest results that the client could use and live with, thanks for the excellent answers!

Answer (score 2):

You could compile a list of the possible combinations you want to test into a `List<Tuple<int, int>>`
and then select the maximum

```
 mylist.Select(i => new [] { Tuple.New(i.X, i.Y}, Tuple.New(i.X, i.Z), Tuple.New(i.Y, i.Z)})
       .Max(t => compareElements(t.First, t.Second))
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if it is what you are searching for, but I would try to use LINQ in this way:

```
var linq = from el1 in list
           from el2 in list
           where el1 != el2
           select CompareFunction(el1, el2);

int max = linq.Max();
```

Comparison sample implementation:

```
int CompareFunction(string a, string b)
{
    return a.Length - b.Length;
}
```

This way you compare each element against the other elements in the list (it is a sort of permutation I think) except itself, then select the comparison value and finally the highest value.

Comment: Wouldn't that still repeat comparisons? If list contains items 1, 2, 3; it would compare 1-2, then 1-3, then 2-1, 2-3, finally 3-1 and 3-2.  1-2 is a duplicate of 2-1, 1-3 is a duplicate of 3-1 and 2-3 is a duplicate of 3-2.

Comment: I thought of that, but it doesn't address the problem that it'll run duplicate code.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much the same as a couple given, but doesn't require one to assign to a list first.

```
List<Element> soFar = new List<Element>();
// If I expected a good few duplicate values, and if 
// compareElements(x, x) isn't 100% - i.e. it's not a similarity
// check for example, then I'd use HashSet<Element> and skip
// when .Add() fails.

int result = 0;
foreach(Element el in sourceEnumeration)
{
  for(int i = 0; i != soFar.Count; ++i)
  {
    int cmp = compareElements(el, soFar[i]);
    if(cmp > result)
    {
      if(cmp == 100)
        return 100;
      cmp = result;
    }
  }
  soFar.Add(el);
}
return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

An unreadable LINQ implementation (may not compile, I haven't tested):

```
Enumerable.Range(0, listOfElements.Length).ToList().ForEach(i=>Enumerable.Range(i, listOfElements.Length-i-1).ToList().ForEach(j=>compareElements(listOfElements[i], listOfElements[j]))).Max();
```